# JSON API: How to make sure a resource belongs to current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, json-api

Need some help with JSON API structure.

Say we have the following:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :comments
 belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post
 has_many :talkbacks
end

class Talkbacks < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :comment
end
```

Now, the api points should be something like the following:

```
/posts
/posts/:id
/posts/:id/comments
/comments
/comments/:id
/comments/:id/talkbacks
/talkbacks
/talkbacks/:id
```

If we'd like to show a post, making sure posts belong to the current user is easy assuming we have a token:

```
# /posts/:id
current_user.posts.find_by_id!(params_id)
```

However, if we want to show a specific talkback, it is more difficult to make sure the talkback belongs to the user:

```
# /talkbacks/:id
```

What would be the best way to make sure the user can access to that talkback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should flesh out your relationships with a `has_one, through` relation. Then, it's easy to perform the query. You don't need to add a user_id to the task field (and shouldn't as the post should handle that association). The `has_one` relation allows you do effectively have a `belongs_to` relation through another model and removes the need to have a join table.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
  has_many :talkbacks, through: :comments
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments
  has_many :tasks, through: :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post

  has_one :user, through: :post

  has_many :talkbacks
end

class Talkbacks < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment

  has_one :user, through: :comment
end
```

Then you can do, in your controller,

```
current_user.talkbacks.find(params[:id])
```

As an aside in your post...

```
current_user.posts.find_by_id!(params_id)
```

`posts.find_by_id!()` is equivalent to `posts.find()` so you don't need to do the `by_id!` part. By default, Rails will raise an exception if it cannot find a record with the `find` method, same as using the bang on a `find_by_id` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
talkback = Talkback.find(params[:id])
if talkback
  if talkback.comment.post.user == current_user
    # do stuff
  else
    # talkback doesn't belong to signed in user
  end
else
  # no talkback exists with that id in the database
end
```

Or you could encapsulate that logic in the model and use a method like this:

### talkbacks_controller.rb

```
talkback = Talkback.find(params[:id])
if talkback
  if talkback.belongs_to_user?
    # do stuff
  else
    # talkback doesn't belong to signed in user
  end
else
  # no talkback exists with that id in the database
end
```

### talkbalk.rb (model class)

```
def belongs_to_user?(user = current_user)
  self.comment.post.user == user
end
```

This method users the current signed in user as the default if no parameter to the method is specified.

Comment: Yap, thanks. So there aren't magic solutions here just deep queries?

Comment: unfortunately no, not with the current setup

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the user_id to the talkbacks table and then set up the association between them. I think it will make your life easier doing that then trying to make a deep nesting call. (I would also consider changing the name of the Talkbacks class to singular "Talkback" so you stick with the naming conventions of Rails.)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :talkbacks
end

class Talkback
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then you can make the call:

```
# /talkbacks/:id
current_user.talkbacks.find_by_id!(params_id)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just en example for the question, a post could actually have multiple users to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with has_many :through.
Look at this [post](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/complex-has-many-through/).